# Store regular expressions for use throughout web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, webforms

I have a web application that contains many forms with textbox fields on for dates and URLs etc.

I am using `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator>` to validate the textbox content and wondered if there was a way I could centrally store the expressions I am using in something like a web.config file so I can easily reference them each time I add a `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator>`, rather than having to type out the entire regex i.e.

**Regex store**

```
string urlRegEx = "(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})"
```

**Web form**

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression=urlRegEx>
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to be able to change them without recompiling? If not, maybe you could just use a static class with some read only properties?

Comment: You can save them to disk, save them to database, save them in settings, put them in application scope. There are many, many ways to persist those strings. Probably the easiest would be to store them in a text file if you don't already use a database. This all assumes you need to change them after compile. If not, then use application scope or a public static class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically create a Resources file in the ASP.NET `App_GlobalResources` folder to centralize all my string constants and then reference the string in the markup. For this example I created a `RegexStrings.resx` resource file and added a key `URL` with a value containing your regular expression string:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="UrlTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="UrlRegEx" runat="server"     
                                ErrorMessage="Invalid url." 
                                ControlToValidate="UrlTextBox"     
                                ValidationExpression="<%$ Resources:RegexStrings, URL %>" />
```

See [ASP.NET Web Page Resources Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx) for details